# NgBootbox with two way binding template not working

Tags: angularjs

i have here an input button where i want to set its message using a template.At first, when i clicked the button it should run a function which will set scope.info value to info, and then the modal should popup containing the template which has the two way binding. but the binding is not working

```
Code:

index.html
        <input
    type="button"
    name="name"
    value="New"
    ng-click="verify()"
    ng-bootbox-title="Warning"
    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog
    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template="temp.html"
    ng-bootbox-buttons="customDialogButtons"
    ng-bootbox-class-name="some-class" />

temp.html
<div>{{info}}</div>

prog.js
    $scope.verify = function(){
     $scope.infos= "info";
   };

SOLVED!

SOLUTION: 
    prog.js
    $scope.verify = function(){
     $rootScope.infos= "info";
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works correctly, you just miss spelled the name of your variable (`{{infos}}`) in your `div`.

**[JSFiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/mL2Lrs00/)**.

---

### Update from comments

Try to put infos value in `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`, it seems you have an issue of **accessibility**.

Comment: i fixed that. but binding in the temp.html is not showing

Comment: heres the squence of the logic. when i clicked the button it should run the verify function and set the scope.infos value. and then it will popup the modal that has a content from the temp.html which has the two way binding. unfortunately, temp.html always get a empty string not the value of the new scope.infos

Comment: It seems you didn't provide this code... Can you try to put `infos` value in `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`, and tell me if it works better.

Comment: alright. this solves the problem. Thumbs up for you sir!